# Netplan listen to a range of IP addresses

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, netplan

I have purchased a range of IP addresses. I want to bind all the available addresses to my VPS.

I have configured Netplan this way:

```
user@server:/etc/netplan# cat 60-static.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: yes
      addresses:
        - 1.2.3.4/29
```

Currently i am only able to ssh to the address 1.2.3.4 but i also want to the server to listen to 1.2.3.5-1.2.4.12. What can i do to make sure my server listens to all available addresses?

Answer (score 0):

add just one more; it must be a host: - 1.2.3.12/32